# using XQuery to search through multiple files for a specified XPath and its value(s)

Tags: csv, search, xpath, xquery, saxon

I want to search through my XML files for a specified XPath defined. I'd rather avoid using `grep` with some complex multi-line handling pattern and decided to use XQuery for this purpose. I'm on MacOS so the easiest I've found was to install Saxon as my [XQuery](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xquery/) engine for this:

```
brew install saxon
```

First I was bit puzzled why the command line tool `saxon` doesn't seem to support XQuery:

```
saxon -qs:"collection('file:///Temp?select=*.xml')//group[1]/product[1]/@prd_id"
Command line option -qs is not recognized. Options available:  -? -a -catalog -config -cr -diag -dtd -ea -expand -explain -export -ext -im -init -it -l -license -m -nogo -now -o -opt -or -outval -p -pack -quit -r -repeat -s -sa -scmin -strip -t -T -threads -TJ -TP -traceout -tree -u -val -versionmsg -warnings -x -xi -xmlversion -xsd -xsdversion -xsiloc -xsl -xsltversion -y
```

Then I discovered I can use a jar lib (*`/usr/local/Cellar/saxon/9.7.0.4/libexec/saxon9he.jar`*) instead.

What I want is to get two things: (1)**list of files** (ideally just file names) that have the XPath:

`/OTA_AirBookRS/Warnings/Warning`

present along (2)**with the content found** there (tag could be as well empty, but still present: `</warning>`)

I was playing with this for a good while but couldn't get a combination that would give me both: **filename** and tag **value**. This is as far as I've got:

```
#findWarnings.qs:
for $pnr in collection('file:///Users/magick/pnr?select=pnr*.xml') return <file>{fn:concat("full path: ",fn:base-uri($pnr))}</file>
```

running it by:

```
java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -q:findWarnings.qs
```

I'm getting back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><file>full path: file:/Users/magick/pnr/pnr_22F47B_farelock.xml</file><file>full path: file:/Users/magick/pnr/pnr_22Q73S_edw13.xml</file><file>full path: file:/Users/magick/pnr/pnr_22UP2W_fare_calc.xml</file><file>full path: file:/Users/magick/pnr/pnr_22UT32_fare_calc2.xml</file><file>full path: file:/Users/magick/pnr/pnr_22VZGN_2_grp_update.xml</file>
```

---

I will be grateful if someone could help me get on the right track, in particular:

1. How to limit the list of files by those that have XPath present. I've tried to put XPath after collection(…)`/OTA_AirBookRS/Warnings/Warning` but either doesn't work or looses the file paths in the output
2. Rather than one stream of values, how to produce row-by-row result:

   ```
   <file>File path: pnr_22Q73S_edw13.xml</file><value>Bad ticketing!</value>
   <file>File path: pnr_22UT32_fare_calc2.xml</file><value>Exchange missing</value>
   ```
3. Is it possible to produce tsv (tab separated) file instead of pseudo XML. I've tried but find that it stops working after I remove `'<tags>'` from `return` statement…
4. Is there a way to limit the output to maximum 3 entries found **per file**?
5. How to use functions? Ie. I see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xquery/xquery_concat.htm) `concat(…)` syntax should be enough but I find it doesn't work unless I put a prefix: `fn:concat`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'm afraid I have no idea what "brew install saxon" installs on your machine. It's not a Saxonica-supported installation mechanism. I guess it was created by some third party and I have no idea of its status. Judging from the command line options available, it is a synonym of (some version of) net.sf.saxon.Transform, which runs XSLT rather than XQuery.

There are two ways you could do this.

- You could use the `uri-collection()` function to get the list of files, and then process each of them individually using the `doc()` function. This is useful if you want to handle different files differently based on their name, or if you want to sort them by name, etc.
- Alternatively you can use the `collection()` function to retrieve all the documents, and then for each one, use the `document-uri()` function to get the URI by which it was retrieved (in most cases `base-uri()` will also work).

Let's take the second approach. Your specific questions:

> *(1) How to limit the list of files by those that have XPath present.*

Use a predicate.

```
collection('files?select=*.xml')[/OTA_AirBookRS/Warnings/Warning]/
  <file>File name: {document-uri(.)}</file>
```

> *(2) Rather than one stream of values, how to produce row-by-row result:*

Use `!indent=yes` on the command line, or `declare output:indent="yes";` in the query prolog.

> *(3) Is it possible to produce tsv (tab separated) file instead of pseudo XML.*

Yes, use output method text, again selected either using `!method=text` on the command line, or declare output in the query prolog.

> *(4) Is there a way to limit the output to maximum 3 entries found per file?*

I don't think you've said what an "entry" is, but a predicate `[position() le 3]` in the right place should do the job.

> *(5) How to use functions? Ie. I see here `concat(…)` syntax should be enough but I find it doesn't work unless I put a prefix: fn:concat*

I don't know what you did wrong. Unprefixed function names should work fine.

Comment: "brew" here refers to Homebrew, a popular macOS package manager. (If you're interested, the Homebrew "recipe" for Saxon is here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/saxon.rb. The "write_jar_script" invoked in that script is defined here: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb#L437-L444.) I have a little alias for having Saxon execute XQuery, "saxonxq": https://gist.github.com/joewiz/f44a29c61ae23b16b478dfabe0fefbac.

Comment: Putting it all together, an example that selects the first three warnings from each file, produces text output tab separated with a carriage return and line-feed for each entry: `for $pnr in collection('file:///Users/magick/pnr/?select=pnr*.xml')/OTA_AirBookRS/Warnings/Warning[position() le 3] return concat("full path: ", base-uri($pnr), "&#9;", string($pnr), "&#10;&#13;")`